# Discord selfbot checks for other users

Tags: python, discord, bots, self, whitelist

I've been working on a Discord selfbot just to learn discord.py better and im having an issue, Im trying to make it so that if someone else who I whitelisted which would put their id in a .txt file they can run commands and I will respond with the answer to that command for example,

Someone whitelisted: '+ping'

Me: 'pong!'

Here is my current code:

```py
client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', self_bot=True,
                      fetch_offline_members=False)

def checkforuser(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == 669311027615105030

@client.command()
@commands.check(checkforuser)
async def ping(ctx):
   await ctx.send('Pong!')
```

Its not working and not erroring, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: At a glance it looks like the user would have to type "$pong" to trigger that command.  Can you show more code?

Comment: @afic fixed, added more code

Answer (score 0):

Try `await ctx.send('Pong!')` instead of `ctx.send('Pong!')`. Also, you can remove `client = discord.Client()` since you defined a new value for client in the next line.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but this is not my issue, just a typo

Answer (score 0):

I'm composing this answer for everyone with this specific question.

I suggest you make a command to whitelist others, if you don't want to do that manually.

Here's your check

```py
def checkforuser(ctx: commands.Context):
    """
    Returns True if the user appears to be found in the whitelist.txt
    False if the user wasn't found in the whitelist.txt
    """
    with open("whitelist.txt") as f:
        user_ids = [int(line.strip("\n")) for line in f.readlines()]
        return ctx.author.id in user_ids
```

### Reference

[Python built-in `open()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)